# Turn off images within a table from a button

Tags: php, html, image

I have an inventory system that generates a website each night containing 200+ items and images. One image/item/price per table row. All items are within a single table.

I can add/edit the html after it's been generated with an automation program that I use.
(Automate 9 by Network Automation)

Is there a way to add a button before the table that could switch off all the images within the table? Images are taking up space and if someone were to print off the site. It would be about 10 pages. 3 pages if the images were turned off. Basically I want to make it printer friendly without having to make a copy of the site and remove the images tags from the copy site.

I've been googling for a while and not coming up with a single idea. Kinda tells me it may not be possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a CSS file specifically for printing that hides the images.

Just add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />`

And then inside print.css:

```
#mytable img { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at print CSS. Hiding the pictures will only be a matter of `img {display:none;}` in a print-specific CSS, and you could aswell get rid of other unwanted stuff on your page, like navigation which is also useless on printed page...